# How to perform Unit testing and Code coverage in IAR

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage, iar

I am using IAR embedded workbench 8.0. I would like to use C-spy debugger to perform unit testing and code coverage.Is there any way so that i can generate xml files and use it with jenkins to display the coverage report?

Thanks,
Apoorva

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your problem in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots you've tried to solve it on your own. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good choice for displaying XML coverage results in Jenkins is the free [Emma plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/emma).

The plugin consumes EMMA-XML files. C-SPY cannot produce this format directly but nothing stops you from making use of a 3rd party coverage tool alongside with the unit testing. That way you can run the tests on the hardware as opposed to merely simulating them.

Just look out for a coverage tool that can hook into the build step and has the required EMMA-XML format among its reporting options.

Note that the compiler shipping with IAR Workbench is a bit special. At least when used from the IDE its command line semantics differ in some aspects from compilers like gcc. One of my colleagues has managed to properly intercept invocations of the compiler using our company's coverage tool [Coco](https://www.froglogic.com/coco/), however. Feel free to inquire with our support team for the required setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the IAR Workbench itself contains any GUI for unit tests, however if you are OK using 3rd-party tools, you can use Visual Studio with the VisualGDB plugin to create unit tests with the IAR compiler and run them via JTAG/SWD. You can find a detailed tutorial on this topic here: [Creating Unit Tests for IAR-based Projects](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/iar/tests/)

Code Coverage is trickier because the IAR compiler may not be able to instrument the code to gather the necessary information, but it you are OK using gcc instead, you can set it up as shown [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/profiler/embedded/coverage/).